# How can I export particular org files/headings with export settings to specified filenames?

Tags: org-mode, elisp, org-export

I'd like to export headings with particular names/tags, with a particular set of export options, to particular file locations.

I'd like to do this all via elisp, so that I can have it part of a larger script which then pushes the changes to server. Also there will be multiple sets of overlapping documents/headings exported in different ways, so having all the settings in separate elisp scripts using project-alists allows more flexibility then adding annotations to the files or headings themselves.

As a concrete example, I might want to output `a.org::*h` to `foo.html` and `b.org` to `bar.html`, with a set of publish settings. `foo.html` in this case should only contain the contents of the `h` heading, with child headings of `h` exported as top level headings in `foo.html`.

The only way I can see how to do this is to hackily pre-process with a script that copies over parts I want into a new directory (into files with those specific names) and then publishing from there. I'm not sure how to do that in a way that doesn't have unexpected side effects, and am curious if there is a better way?

An ideal solution would enable me to:

- Specify headings to export, and corresponding output file names.
- Use project-alist so that I can describe other export settings and combine these export "projects" as needed.
- Ensure links worked, even as headings are transformed into separate files.

Comment: I think that much of what you want to do may be accomplished through customizing `org-publish-project-alist`, but maybe you will have to write your own export function.

Comment: I can't see how either of those would help given my reading of the docs and source code, can you elaborate? `org-publish-project-alist` doesn't let you specify headings to export (though I might use it's pre/post-process directives), and I'm not sure what the benefit would be of writing a new export function. I realized this is a "big" question, so I broke it up a little and seperately asked: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14090/export-a-particular-heading-with-elisp

Comment: Yes, this is roughly as I imagined (I thought using `:completion-function` would be something like what you wanted, though probably I was wrong).