# Export a particular org heading with elisp?

Tags: org-mode, elisp, org-export

I'd like to specify a heading (using either link or agenda syntax) and export just that heading as a file, using elisp.

I'm not trying to do this - since this specifies the file to export to in the file itself: [How to export top-level headings of org-mode buffer to separate files?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/how-to-export-top-level-headings-of-org-mode-buffer-to-separate-files)

I think it might involve specific input to `org-export-as`? (a function in `ox.el`)

Comment: Maybe a combination of `org-link-search` with `org-narrow-to-subtree`? I think, by default, Org will export the narrowed buffer rather than the entire document.

Comment: That helped a bit, and I discovered `save-excursion` which helps not mess up document state as I do things (I'm relatively new to elisp). This is a step in the right direction: `(save-excursion (org-link-search link-string) (org-html-export-to-html nil t nil '())`. However, it doesn't for example make the title the selected heading, or keep normal export options, even if I replace `'()` with a call to `org-export-get-environment`.